# How do square brackets work in sscanf?

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read line made of integer and quoted strings with `sscanf`.
My formating string is something like `"\"%m[^\"]s\" , %x"`. `sscanf` gives a string inside quotes but does not give rest of input in second field. I also tried `"\"%m[^\"]s%c"`, so closing quote should go into `%c`. `sscanf` again only gives one field. With just `%s` it works, with `%[]s` it does not.

Comment: The `s` is not part of the `%[` format specifier. Drop it.

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the input string is `"\"Hello there\", 32"` then this is how `sscanf()` reads it with the formatting string `"\"%m[^\"]s\" , %x"`:

- `\"` in the formatting string matches with `\"` in the input (and it is discarded).
- `%m[^\"]`<sup>1</sup> matches with `Hello there`.
- `s` in the formatting string **does not match** with `\"` so the scanning ends.

The formatting string you want to use is `"\"%m[^\"]\" , %x"`

For more on `sscanf()` and it's formatting string, read http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf and/or [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html).

<sup>1</sup> Note that the `m` modifier is not standard C (even though it is part of the `POSIX standard).

Comment: Note that `m` in `%m[^\"]` is employing a non-standard extension to the Standard C library.

Comment: @chux Yes, I know, the `m` modifier is a POSIX extension. I just assumed that OP would be working on a POSIX setup since he was using it and therefore it would not be the cause of his problem. But for future readers, I'll add a note to my answer.